# Scala reading CSV data with multiple record types directly into data classes

Tags: scala, csv, reflection

I have a CSV file to process, with multiple record types.  The first column of each row tells me which type of data it is.  I have written a data class for each row (there are over 30) and while I could hand write a contructor for each data class which accepts an Array[String] from the parser as these records have upto a maximum of 35 fields that is error prone and messy.

As there are multiple record types, there is obviously no first line with field names.

I am using Scala 2.11, so I thought how about using reflection, and rather than using the underlying Java reflection I can of course use Scala reflection directly, but I am having difficulty understand how.

So what I need to do is to:-

- For each row in the file, read and parse the record into columns
- Based on the field column create one of the right data class
- for each field in the data object
- based on the field type, convert the column and save it in the object

Now this relied on the fields remaining in the same order, does Scala guarantee that?

Also I have found lots of examples showing how to find the fields for a class, but I have not yet found how to get and set values into the fields.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Here are the first two records:-

`990001,DD002,1995,20150723,143937,O,NMR,Impel Pro,1998v1.00,,,NMR,1998v2.00
091017,1,HOLSTEIN,HF,D ,N,12,99,280,999,305,1,0.1,3,75,99.9,1.5,1.5,7,7,1,1,7,7,0,0,9,9,22000,25000,29000,32000,15,65,1,1047,Y,Y,C`

The first record is a header, the second is a definition of a Breed of cattle, in this case a Holstein.  990001 means header and is represented in my code as a Header object, and 091017 means breed, and is represented as a Breed object.

I want to load the Header into:-

`class Header(var dataDictionaryType: String = "",
             var isoVersion: String = "",
             var createdOrUploadedDate: Option[LocalDate] = Some(null),
             var createdOrUploadedTime: Option[LocalTime] = Some(null),
             var systemStatus: String = "",
             var senderName: String = "",
             var receiverName: String = "",
             var adedNationalVersion:String = "",
             var processComputerType: String = "",
             var adedManufacturerVersion: String = ""`

Note that there needs to be a few extra Options added.

Comment: Can you post an example of your input? (possibly reduced to 2-4 columns rather than all 35) I'm not sure I get what you are describing.